# StarterGUI not editable through scripts

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically, I have this code where when you click a button it adds to this invisible "click counter" located in the player's character. but then, when it reaches 100 clicks its supposed to change the name of another gui to "Rebirth" for a simulator like thing im making in my game. If the name of it is "Rebirth", then it will enable another script which is what happens when you click the rebirth button. Thing is, it doesn't work. The name technically IS changing, but not visually. If you look in the properties for the rebirth button, the name does change technically, but in game it just stays at it's original name, which is "Music".
Its the same thing with the script. Technically it is enabled but it doesn't do anything.

I did notice that there was a part of the code that was seperated by these 2 "end" things. So I fixed that and it stayed EXACTLY the same. But the thing is this has been happening to all of my games, not just this one im making with this simulator thing in it. For example another game I made tried to have something where 15 seconds after spawning in the screen turns completely black using a StarterGUI pitch black frame I made. But the code where it would enable the frame after 15 seconds didn't work. In properties it was enabled, but not visually. I am very confused and don't know what's happening at all. Oh yeah and here's the code:

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local button = script.Parent
local button2 = game.StarterGui.RebirthGUI.Frame.TextButton

local ClickStats = Instance.new("Folder",Player.Character)
ClickStats.Name = "ClickStats"

local Clicks = Instance.new("IntValue")
Clicks.Name = "Clicks"
Clicks.Parent = ClickStats
Clicks.Value = 0

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    Clicks.Value = Clicks.Value + 1
    if Clicks.Value > 100 then
        print("it works guys")
        button2.Text = "Rebirth"
if button2.Text == "Rebirth" then
    button2.RebirthScript.Enabled = true
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

StarterGUI is not where GUIs that are attached to players are found. They are found in PlayerGui.

On line 3 instead of

```lua
local button2 = game.StarterGui.RebirthGUI.Frame.TextButton
```

You need to do:

```lua
local button2 = Player.PlayerGui.RebirthGUI.Frame.TextButton
```